# How can I change vector grid extents in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I created many vector grids, but later I discovered that I need to modify some of their extents, hence, How can I change vector grid's extents (xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax) in QGIS?

Comment: More information is needed to answer this question

Answer (score 1):

Simply enlarging the extent does not create additional grid lines, nor makes it the existing lines longer.

The vector grid is simply a bunch of lines or polygons. You are quicker to create a new grid than trying to extend the existing one.

Comment: Plugins like e.g. MMQGIS makes this a quickand painless task.

Answer (score 0):

The layer extent is taken from the `Layer Spatial Reference System`. You can see it going to `Layer properties > Metadata` :

[image]

Therefore, to have a new extent you need to specify a custom CRS for your layer, using the `Settings` menu and then choosing `Custom CRS` :

[image]

As stated in the `Custom Coordinate Reference System` section, from the `Working with projections` chapter in the [QGIS User Manual](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html), *defining a custom CRS in QGIS requires a good understanding of the Proj.4 projection library*.

Eventually, you need to go to `Layer properties > General` to specify you custom CRS, and pressing `Update extents` :

[image]